# 504 Gateway Time-out on HostGator

Tags: http-status-code-504

Is anyone else hosting with HostGator Reseller? They seem to just be getting worse and worse over time. I am having **multiple** short 504 Gateway Time-out errors on a couple of websites and am waiting wondering what other websites of mine it's happening on that I am yet to realise.

They are both WordPress sites. HostGator support (well after two live chats they finally escalated) said it might be due 'enormous network payloads' but I'm not sure it's only down to that as it wasn't that bad.

Anyone having the same issues, or ideas? I have no problems with SiteGround.

Thanks,

[image]

Snippet of downtime:
[image]